# In asp.net web application, can add wcf service class?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application, in which i have added wcf service item using add new item menu. Is it possible to having a webserivce in web application? If yes, can be called from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have a web service in a web application and you should be able to call the service from the client.  For example, I've called wcf services in my web application using either jquery or asp.net ajax.